# Trie Data Structure in Finding an Optimal Solution

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, trie

This Question is part of ongoing Competition , I have solved the 75% of this Question Data Set but the 25% is giving me TLE. I am asking why it's is giving `TLE`  an i am sure my complexity is `O(n*n)`
**Question:**
String S consisting of N lowercase English alphabets. We has prepared a list L consisting of `all non empty substrings of the string S`.
Now he asks you Q questions. To ith question, you need to count the number of ways to choose exactly Ki equal strings from the list L
For Example:

```
    String  = ababa
L = {"a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "ab", "ba", "ab", "ba", "aba", "bab", "aba", "abab", "baba", "ababa"}.
k1 = 2: There are seven ways to choose two equal strings ("a", "a"), ("a", "a"), ("a", "a"), ("b", "b"), ("ab", "ab"), ("ba", "ba"), ("aba", "aba").
k2 = 1: We can choose any string from L (15 ways).
k3 = 3: There is one way to choose three equal strings - ("a", "a", "a").
k4 = 4: There are no four equal strings in L .
```

[Question LINK](http://www.codechef.com/JUNE15/problems/CHSTR/)
**My approach**

I am making a TRIE of IT and **Calculating The and Array F[i]** where F[i] represent the number of times i equal String Occur.
My TRIE:

```
 static class Batman{

        int value;
        Batman[] next = new Batman[26];

        public Batman(int value){
            this.value = value;
            } 
 }
```

**MY Insert Function**

```
 public static void  Insert(String S,int[] F , int start){

     Batman temp = Root;
     for(int i=start;i<S.length();i++){
         int index = S.charAt(i)-'a';

         if(temp.next[index]==null){
             temp.next[index] = new Batman(1);
             F[1]+=1;

         }else{
             temp.next[index].value+=1;
             int xx = temp.next[index].value;
             F[xx-1]-=1;
             F[xx]+=1;

            // Calculating The Frequency of I equal Strings
         }
         temp = temp.next[index];
     }

 }
```

**MY MAIN FUNCTION**

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws  java.lang.Exception  {

Root = new Batman(0);
int n = in.nextInt();
int Q = in.nextInt();
String S = in.next();
int[] F = new int[n+1];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    Insert(S,F,i);


long[] ans = new long[n+1];


for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=i;j<=n;j++){
        ans[i]+= F[j]*C[j][i];  // C[n][k] is the Binomial Coffecient
        ans[i]%=mod;
    }
}


 while(Q>0){
     Q--;
    int cc = in.nextInt();
    long o =0;
    if(cc<=n) o=ans[cc];
     System.out.println(o+" "+S.length());
 }
}
```

Why My appraoch is giving TLE as time Complexity is O(N*N) ans the length of String is N<=5000. Please Help me [Working CODE](http://ideone.com/zUiTLL)

Comment: Do keep in mind that `10n*n` and `1000000n*n`  both `O(n*n)` .

Comment: @azurefrog i could not understand you please explain

Comment: When thinking about ["Big O" notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o), and especially when you are trying to [calculate it for your program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it), you need to keep in mind that when n is small (like in your example), the quadratic term will dominate the total time much less than when n is large. Just because your program is O(n*n) doesn't mean it'll run quickly, just that the scaling of its runtime will vary with the square of the input size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason this program get TLE (keep in mind that time constraint is 1 sec):

Each time you create a `Batman` object, it will create an array with length [26], and it is equivalence to adding a loop with n = 26.

So, you time complexity is 26*5000*5000 = 650000000 = 6.5*10^8 operations, theoretically, it can still fit into time limit if CPU speed is 10^9 operations per sec, but also keep in mind that there are some heavy calculation stuffs after this, so, this should be the reason.

To solve this problem, I used [Z-algorithm](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107) and get accepted: [Link](http://www.codechef.com/JUNE15/status/CHSTR,vozcoder)

The actual code is quite complex, so the idea is, you have a table `count[i][j]`, which is the number of substring that matched substring (i, j). Using Z-algorithm, you can have a time complexity of O(n^2).

For each string `s`:

```
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int q = in.nextInt();
        String s = in.next();
        int[][] cur = new int[n][];
        int[][] count = new int[n][n];
        int[] length = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cur[i] = Z(s.substring(i).toCharArray());//Applying Z algorithm
            for (int j = 1; j < cur[i].length; j++) {
                if (cur[i][j] > length[j + i]) {
                    for (int k = i + length[j + i]; k < i + cur[i][j]; k++) {
                        count[i][k]++;
                    }
                    length[j + i] = cur[i][j];
                }

            }
        }
        int[] F = new int[n + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = i; j < n; j++){
                int v = count[i][j] + (length[i] < (j - i + 1) ? 1 : 0);
                F[v]++;
            }
        }
```

Z-algorithm method:

```
public static int[] Z(char[] s) {
    int[] z = new int[s.length];
    int n = s.length;
    int L = 0, R = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (i > R) {
            L = R = i;
            while (R < n && s[R - L] == s[R])
                R++;

            z[i] = R - L;

            R--;
        } else {
            int k = i - L;
            if (z[k] < R - i + 1) {
                z[i] = z[k];
            } else {
                L = i;
                while (R < n && s[R - L] == s[R])
                    R++;
                z[i] = R - L;
                R--;
            }
        }
    }
    return z;
}
```

Actual code: http://ideone.com/5GYWeS

**Explanation**:

First, we have an array length, with `length[i]` is the longest substring that matched with the string start from index `i`

For each index `i`, after calculate the Z function, we see that, `if cur[i][j] > length[j + i]`, which means, there exists one substring longer than previous substring matched at index `j + i`, and we havent counted them in our result, so we need to count them.

So, even there are 3 nested for loop, but each substring is only counted once, which make this whole time complexity is O(n ^2)

```
        for (int j = 1; j < cur[i].length; j++) {
            if (cur[i][j] > length[j + i]) {
                for (int k = i + length[j + i]; k < i + cur[i][j]; k++) {
                    count[i][k]++;
                }
                length[j + i] = cur[i][j];
            }          
        }
```

For below loop, we notice that, if there is a matched for substring (i,j), `length[i] >= length of substring (i,j)`, but if there is no matched, we need to add 1 to count substring (i,j), as this substring is unique.

```
        for(int j = i; j < n; j++){
            int v = count[i][j] + (length[i] < (j - i + 1) ? 1 : 0);
            F[v]++;
        }
```

Comment: If you look at my `Insert` function which is of O(n) and i am calling it `n` times in my main function so overall `O(n*n)`

Comment: @user4996457 you are correct about it, just updated my answer

Comment: so which data structure or approach should to follow

Comment: I dont know the Z algorithm i will learn it and pin you if i found some problem but my Trie solution on my local machine is running fine on large data set

Comment: @user4996457 This problem is extremely tight on time limit :)

Comment: Explain this : ` for (int j = 1; j < cur[i].length; j++) {
                if (cur[i][j] > length[j + i]) {
                    for (int k = i + length[j + i]; k < i + cur[i][j]; k++) {
                        count[i][k]++;
                    }
                    length[j + i] = cur[i][j];
                }

            }
        }`

Comment: and this ` int v = count[i][j] + (length[i] < (j - i + 1) ? 1 : 0);
                F[v]++;`

Comment: @user4996457 explanation added.

Comment: @user4996457 Look like the author also used Z algorithm to solve this. [Link](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/71518/chstr-editorial)